Manage the amount of data on tables
I can have several tables with 10+ millions rows in by year.
I would to know what's the best approach to maintain responsiveness with this amount of datas and I have two ideas.

Don't touch these tables in the time, hoping that with the design of the database it will still be responsive despite data quantity

Copy the structure of these tables in archive tables and move old datas in, in order to keep "production tables" reduced


Or do you have other ideas?
I can't delete old datas because we have to make statistics over several years.

Move whatever data is not actively needed in day to day process to archive tables (or if you dont need it at all delete it).

Best implies asking for opinions. Best for what, speed, size, number of rows?

Speed is important for our customers


10M rows/year is less than 1/sec.  100 simple queries per second is not a problem
What do the SELECTs look like?  If they are getting slower and slower, then they are probably doing "table scans" and would probably benefit greatly from indexing.  (No, don't blindly "index every column".  Let's see the queries.)
Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for advice on dataypes.  (Example: don't blindly use an 8-byte BIGINT when a 1-byte TINYINT will suffice.)
Will you be purging "old" data after some number of months?  If so plan now by using Partitioning
If some selects are taking sums/averages/etc over many months' worth of data, use Summary Tables
You probably you can "delete old data" -- Keep the summary tables, but purge the raw data.  The summary data is both faster and smaller.  Win, win.
If the table holds "sensor" (weather, vehicle, etc) data, see https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor for more tips.
innodb_buffer_pool_size should be about 70% of available RAM.
(I say "no" to both of your bullet items!)

